# No virtual method createCaptureSessionByOutputConfigurations(Ljava/util/List;Landroid/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession$StateCallback;Landroid/os/

Tags: react-native, build, expo

I'm using the `react-native-vision-camera` module in my react native project and expo

When testing on an SM-J500M, Samsung J5 cell phone, I receive this result in `onError`, the camera goes black and nothing else happens, how can I fix it?

> [unknown/unknown]: [unknown/unknown] No virtual method
> createCaptureSessionByOutputConfigurations(Ljava/util/List;Landroid/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession$StateCallback;Landroid/os/Handler;)V
> in class Landroid/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice; or its super classes
> (declaration of 'android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice' appears in
> /system/framework/framework.jar)

I tried update modules, search on chatgpt and duck duck go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method was added in [API level 24](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice#createCaptureSessionByOutputConfigurations(java.util.List%3Candroid.hardware.camera2.params.OutputConfiguration%3E,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback,%20android.os.Handler)).

The Samsung J5 launched on Android 5.0 (API level 21), but should be updatable to Android N, API level 24, which would be new enough.  But if it's not updated to that, that method won't be available and alternatives would need to be used for those older API levels.  So check the OS version on your phone to start with.